# bittrix GetSectionElementsCount filter

Tags: bitrix

I have the following task. We have a property website. in the main page there are the list of free apartments, but the code shows all apartments free and occupied

```
<?
$activeElements = CIBlockSection::GetSectionElementsCount(12, Array("CNT_ACTIVE"=>"Y"));
echo $activeElements;
?>
```

We have the select option (STATUS/XML_URL) in admin panel where we can specify property status (free/occupied)

how can i change the code to display only free apartments? hope for your help

```
<?
$activeElements = CIBlockSection::GetSectionElementsCount(12, Array("CNT_ACTIVE"=>"Y"));
echo $activeElements;
?>
```

Comment: Documentation - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/getsectionelementscount.php .
In array filter, need add, example 'PROPERTY' => array('STATUS' => 'free') 
(the property of the infoblock element can be called differently and meaning, look in admin panel  )